# Rewrite specific action url

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

Is it possible to rewrite specific action url of index?

Example action url:
http://example.com/?action=test or http://example.com/index.php?action=test

If the action of the url is "test" then it will be re written to:
http://example.com/test/

Any help, sample codes or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the other way round? ie. If the URL is `http://example.com/test` then _rewrite_ it to `http://example.com/index.php?action=test`?

Comment: No. What im trying to do is, hide a specific content and display it on specific action like. example:  if($_GET['action'] =='enter'): [show contents]  else : [show button to click enter] endif;  if the url just visited my website example.com he will see the button with the action url http://example.com/?action=enter then when the user choose to enter/click the button, it will show the entire index content. That's why i wanted to rewrite the url from http://example.com/?action=enter into http://example.com/enter/ sorry for my bad english xD

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question how important it is that the query string is `action` and the value `test`, but if all you need to do is have a `/test` URL, and be able to tell if it's the `/test` URL so that you can process soemthing, then the simplest way is probably to use `add_rewrite_endpoint()`. That would look like this:

```
function wpse_279663_rewrite_test() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'test', EP_ROOT ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_279663_rewrite_test' );
```

Now `http://example.com/test` will rewrite to `http://example.com/?test=`. Then you can use `get_query_var()` to see if `?test` is set:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'test', false ) !== false ) {}
```

The 2nd argument says that if `'test'` is not set then return `false` (the default is an empty string, which is useless in this case) so that we can see if it's set or not with a simple true/false.

One way you could use this is in the `init` hook, to process a form or something, like this:

```
function wpse_279663_test() {
    if ( get_query_var( 'test', false ) !== false ) {
        // Do something.
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_279663_test' );
```